# Configure mosquitto broker on windows to available in the network

Tags: windows-server-2012, mqtt, mosquitto

I am currently starting to use MQTT (and mosquitto as a broker) for a home automation project.
I installed mosquitto using the .exe from the homepage on my windows server and I can run it as a service or by directly starting the .exe. Using the _sub and _pub programs I can also publish and suscripe to messages.
Awesome ;)
But (at least by using the standard config) I can't connect from other system in the same LAN. I tried using the said _sub and _pub programs and mqtt-spy, but none of them is able to connect.
Is this a problem with ports and the firewall or with the configuration? I can't find any answers for this only and would be grateful for any help!

If you need any more infos just ask.

Comment: PS I am getting an "unable to open socket par, outgoing publish commands may be delayed" error clientside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok it was a firewall problem I guess. I changed the config to:

```
bind_address #ipAdress
port #Portnumber
```

of course the # fields are the numbers. Then I created 2 rules to allow incoming and outgoing pakets for the mosquitto.exe to pass the firewall. Now it works.

If anyone has more settings/explanation thats usefull, please answer here! There is not a lot of usefull explanation for this on the web.